# How do I create a std::filesystem::exists() compatible path from Windows::Storage::StorageFile?

Tags: c++-cli

I am using a FileOpenPicker to get a file (StorageFile^) in a Windows Universal App. That seems to work fine, and if I output the `StorageFile->Path->Data()`, it returns the expected file path (C:...\MyFile.txt).

When I try to open it and dump the contents to a string things go wrong (the string receives nothing), so as the first step, I was trying to verify the file path with `std::filesystem::exists()`.

To snip it down to the relevant bit:

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(StorageFile^ InFile)
{
    std::filesystem::path FilePath = InFile->Path->Data();

    if (std::filesystem::exists(FilePath))
    {
        //Do things
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get an exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x7780A842 in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location 0x039BC480.
Unhandled exception at 0x7AACF2F6 (ucrtbased.dll) in MyApp.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

Seemingly, the path I attempt to pass into std::filesystem::exists() is invalid.

Any help pointing out where I am going wrong would be very appreciated!

Comment: What does `Data()` return?  IIRC, `path` on windows uses `wchar_t` for the character type.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think that would matter. `std::filesystem::path` is required to be constructible from any character sequence, regardless of whether it's `char`,`wchar_t`,`char8_t`, `char16_t`, or `char32_t` (see the `const Source&` constructor on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path))